# Mail: How to show all recipients by default?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

The top of my Mail messages say `To:` followed by the primary recipient, plus a link labelled `and 3 more…`. Clicking that link reveals the additional recipients.

I'd rather not have to click the link, I'd like to see all recipients always.

The limit appears to be based on length, not kind. Such as, if `To:` recipient's name and email address are short enough, the `Cc:` recipient is then shown.

I've tried clicking `App Prefs / Viewing / Show message headers: Custom…`, then clicking `+`, then typing `To:` and `Cc:` and `Bcc:`, but this doesn't override the apparent length limit.

Is there something I've missed? I've also reported to http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html. Thank you.

Mail: Version 9.3 (3124)

Mac OS X: El Capitan: 10.11.4 (15E65)

Comment: make the window bigger...

Comment: The app window is at maximum size for my 13-inch MacBook Pro. And hiding the left-pane list of mailboxes does not help.